# OpenJDK (build 11.0.3+7) trying to overwrite file in jdk-11+28

Tags: ubuntu

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

dpkg -l | grep openjdk
ii  openjdk-11-jdk                       11+28-0custom0                     all          OpenJDK Development kit (JDK) using Hotspot
ii  openjdk-11.0.2+9                     11.0.2+9                           amd64        OpenJDK 11.0.2+9
```

I have created a Debian package from source code for OpenJDK (build 11.0.3+7) which I got from this site. I have configured puppet to install OpenJDK when pup runs, but for some reason it is trying to overwrite a file in another version of Java 11 that is installed on my host.

I get the following puppet error.

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Java::Java1103-7/Package[openjdk-11.0.3+7]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get q -y -o DPkg::Options::=-force-confold install openjdk-11.0.3+7' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
openjdk-11.0.3+7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 586 MB of archives.
After this operation, 839 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://oppa.ocado.com/dsi/ trusty/ocado openjdk-11.0.3+7 all 11.0.3+7-0custom0 [586 MB]
Fetched 586 MB in 18s (31.5 MB/s)
(Reading database ... 61775 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-11.0.3+7_11.0.3+7-0custom0_all.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-11.0.3+7 (11.0.3+7-0custom0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-11.0.3+7_11.0.3+7-0custom0_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11+28/man/man1/jdeps.1', which is also in package openjdk-11-jdk 11+28-0custom0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-11.0.3+7_11.0.3+7-0custom0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was able to manually workaround this problem by using the force override option.

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite '/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-11.0.3+7_11.0.3+7-0custom0_all.deb'
```

Is there a bug with the OpenJDK 11.0.3+7 package that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

Root cause of the problem...
When I created the package in a folder called javainstall. There were two unpacked packages 11U28 and OpenJDK which were in seperate a sub folders. RPM created the package with the 11U28 and OpenJDK11 packages together, so that is why it was trying to overwrite files in the other package. I fixed it as follows...

```
Make sub folder under javainstall
mkdir OpenJDK1137
cd OpenJDK1137
tar -xzfv ~/Downloads/OpenJDK11U-x64_linux_11.0.3_7.tar.gz

Create the package again

fpm -n openjdk-11.0.3+7 \
    -v 11.0.3+7-0custom0 \
    -a all \
    --vendor openjdk \
    -C /home/nadeem/tmp/javainstall \
    -m "Any meaningful description <email@email.com>" \
    -t deb \
    -s dir \
    --description "OpenJDK 11.0.3+7" \
    --url 'https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v2/info/releases/openjdk11' \
    --prefix /usr/lib/jvm

Confirm it only has the java version I want.
dpkg -c openjdk-11.0.3+7_11.0.3+7-0custom0_all.deb
```

I have only created a package once before and I didn't know it would do that.